# ¿Cómo hacer un formulario de fecha y hora dinámico en html y javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, date, fullcalendar, calendar

Necesito crear un formulario para realizar reservaciones en el cual se tenga que seleccionar primero la hora, pero la hora mínima será 1 hora más de la hora actual, me explico: si son las 3pm la hora mínima de reserva será a partir de las 4pm.

Sin embargo, el segundo campo será la fecha que será a partir del día en transcurso en adelante, pero la otra condición es que si se selecciona un día posterior la hora mínima deberá cambiar.

Ejemplo: hoy es 6 de diciembre y son las 5pm, la hora mínima de reserva podrá ser desde las 6 pero si la fecha de reserva la hago el 7 entonces la hora podrá ser cualquiera por que ya es una fecha posterior. Sé que lo que pido es mucho, pero ya he intentado muchas cosas y he buscado diferentes maneras de hacerlo en el internet, agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un buen ejemplo de cómo hacer un buen calendario para reservas en la siguiente enlace:

https://docs.mobiscroll.com/4-9-0/javascript/calendar

De todas formas, por favor, comparte tu código para que alguien pueda sugerir la mejor forma de implementación del mismo.

Comment: lo intentaré, gracias por el aporte